# JAR Executable file: Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, cucumber-serenity

**Aim:**
Create an executable jar via maven and run it wherever (Local or Jenkins or docker container) required.

**Problem:**
Error: Could not find or load main class boo.EM.TR

*Note: All the below details are sanitized one for security reasons.*

**Folder structure:**

```
projectName (Source root in intellig)
  |
  --> goo/./. 
  --> boo/EM/TR.java
  --> Test/features/*.feature files
  --> coo/./.
  --> target/./.
  pom.xml
  serenity.properties
  settings.xml
```

**TR.java** --> Runner class

```
package boo.EM;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"},
        features = "Test",
        glue = "goo"
)
public class TR {

}
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ABC</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>boo</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>2.6.0</serenity.version>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.29</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-alpha10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.sukgu</groupId>
            <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>boo.EM.TR</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>boo.EM.TR</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Execution steps followed in Command line:**

```
mvn -X clean install -DskipTests=true -s settings.xml  ----> Build Success
java -jar target/boo-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

**Output:**

```
Error: Could not find or load main class boo.EM.TR
```

Question: I am not sure what is wrong in mainclass update in POM.XML. I did try with test/features as well but kept getting the above error again and again in local laptop. Could someone help me please?

Comment: What happens with just `mvn package`?

Comment: @g00se: Command: mvn clean package -DskipTests=true -s settings.xml  | java -jar target/boo-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar | Error: Main method not found in class boo.EM.TR, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: Well *does* that class have a `main` method?

Comment: @g00se: Nope. Here is the content of the class. package boo.EM;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"},
        features = "Test",
        glue = "goo"
)
public class TR {

}

Comment: Well there's your problem's answer ;). You can't run a jar with a class with no `main` method